# Grep the first line of this string and save it in a variable to wget it?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

For example I grep these lines from a url

```
wget -qO- http://superman.com/installer/ | grep "something" 

    href="Superman-Linux-20.0.1222.x64.sh"
    href="Superman-Linux-10.0.1222.x64.sh/*fingerprint*/"
    href="Superman-Linux-10.0.1222.x64.sh/*view*/"
```

I want to grep only

```
Superman-Linux-20.0.1222.x64.sh
```

then I need to wget that

```
wget http://superman.com/installer/Superman-Linux-20.0.1222.x64.sh
```

Comment: Presumably you are getting an HTML response back from the wget command. You should use an HTML parser (or XML if applicable) and obtain the href of the element you're interested in directly.

Comment: are you saying you want the "first" response in the list, or the "shortest", OR the response that doesn't have "/....(fingerprint|view).../" stuff? Please update your Q, rather than reply in comments. Good luck.

Comment: `wget` can follow links. I would suggest letting it figure this out ... assuming there is only one such download link on the page you are fetching, etc.

Comment: that link always update it self .. so the version number change always

Answer (score 2):

Instead of somthing grep like this: `egrep -o "Superman-Linux.*\.sh"`

All in one line do this:

```
wget http://superman.com/installer/$(wget -qO- http://superman.com/installer/ | egrep -o "Superman-Linux.*\.sh")
```

Comment: it didn't work Arash, .. just how to grep "Superman-Linux-20.0.1222.x64.sh"  and delete (herf=") and end at (.sh)

Comment: As i said instead of `| grep something` use `| egrep -o "Superman-Linux.*\.sh"`   

using `egrep -o "Superman-Linux.*\.sh"` would select from Superman........ to .sh

Comment: I checked the url and I Think the page you looking for has changed because I cannot find any line containing `href="Superman-Linux-20.0.1222.x64.sh"`